# Assign values to variable from text file. Search for the string in file. Replace the string in file?

Tags: linux, bash, c

I am working on a project where I need to correct some thousand lines of data. I have already completed the half work and now I am stuck on final part.

I have a file called tree.txt which has list of all nodes, however due to some bug or something many nodes have incorrect tag name.
tree.txt-

```
Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-02:Tag=BA-02
Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-03:Tag=BA-02-1
Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-04:Tag=BA-02-2
```

As seen above tag name of node BA-03 and BA-04 is incorrect, so using file Handling in C I was able to correct this text file and also print all incorrect tags of respective nodes in file like below.
incorrect_tags.txt-

```
"BA-02-1" "BA-03"
"BA-02-2" "BA-04"
```

Now the final thing is there are lot of other files where incorrect tag name is used and I need to replace all those incorrect tags with correct one.

My approach for solving the issue is ->

1. I will have two variables **node** and **tag**, this two variables will get there data from above **incorrect_tag.txt**. I will search for the value of tag in each file and replace it with value of respective node.
2. Once I have finished searching and replacing first tag in all files, it will do same for the remaining ones.

However due to my limited knowledge I don't know whether its possible or not. Also even if I get some help on syntax I would be able to do rest. Thanks

Edit-

The other files where I need to search and replace data are different..
eg Ballast.j1

```
:1176:489:15:30:CompID=118680:Text=BA-02:uiFont=Arial-PLAIN-10: 
:1269:489:15:30:CompID=118681:Text=BA-02-1:uiFont=Arial-PLAIN-10:
:1013:489:15:30:CompID=118677:Text=BA-02-2:uiFont=Arial-PLAIN-10:
```

There are close to 2000 .j1 files where I will search each tag name in all those .j1 files and replace it with correct tag name or node.

Comment: Is all you are trying to do is take each file (eg Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-04) and do a search and replace  BA-02-2 -> BA-04 in that file ?

Comment: You mean to say that Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-03:Tag=BA-02-1 should be re-written like, Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-03:Tag=BA-03 and other should, Main_Overview/Ballast/BA-04:Tag=BA-04 ?

Comment: @davigo I just need to replace all the incorrect tag names present in other files which I have mentioned now, since I need to first know which are incorrect and what is the exact correct name. I have created text file mentioned in second block which contains first old tag name and then new tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply looking for this?

```
sed -i '\%/\([^/:]*\):Tag=\1%n;s%%/\(\([^/:]*\):Tag=\)[^/:-]*-[^/:-]*%\1\2%' *.j1
```

(Try without the `-i` to see the output without writing it back to the original file -- pipe to `less` so you can pause and scroll back and forth.)

The parentheses in the first expression look for a string between a slash and a colon; if we find this immediately followed by `Tag=` and the same string as the one which matched between the parentheses, we are good.  The backslashed parentheses capture this string so we can refer back to it as `\1`.

If we did not find this pattern, the string after `Tag=` must be different from the captured string; if so, replace the string after `Tag=` with the captured string.  The regular expression replaces a sequence which contains a single dash and otherwise no dashes, colons, or slashes (so, up to just before the second dash, or the first slash or colon).

If you are on *BSD (including Mac OS) you need `-i ''` instead of just `-i`.

For another approach, you can refactor your mappings to a `sed` script. If you have a file `incorrect_tags.txt` like

```
"BA-02-1" "BA-03"
"BA-02-2" "BA-04"
```

then you can run the following script

```
sed 's%^"%s/%;s%" "%/%;s%"$%/g%' incorrect_tags.txt
```

which produces ... another `sed` script which now looks like

```
s/BA-02-1/BA-03/g
s/BA-02-2/BA-04/g
```

which you can pass to another instance of `sed` to modify the files which contains these tokens you want to replace.

The full pipeline then is

```
sed 's%^"%s/%;s%" "%/%;s%"$%/g%' incorrect_tags.txt |
sed -i -f - *.j1
```

and again, you might want to try without `-i` first to see what the output looks like.  Also, your `sed` might not like the `-f` option, or might not support reading a script on standard input; perhaps then simply save the output from the first `sed` invocation to a temporary file and then give the temporary file name as the file name argument to `-f`.

Notice that this will require the tags to be non-overlapping -- if you first replace A with B and then B with C, the end result will be as if you had specified "A" "C".  A workaround is to switch the order so that B gets replaced with C first, and only then A with B.

Comment: Thanks but I already did this part using C, final remaining part is I need to replace those old incorrect tag names with new ones but those files are different I have mentioned it now and there are close to 2k files.

Comment: See update now. Using C for this sort of thing is probably misdirected but if you already did that work, you might as well use the results.

Comment: thanks a ton, I never thought sed is so powerful I will need to learn more of it.